# Unable to connect an Xbox Series X|S controller via Bluetooth

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, bluetooth, gamepad

I tried to connect an Xbox Series X|S controller (the one with the share button) to Ubuntu 20.04 via Bluetooth, but the controller keeps disconnecting/reconnecting over and over.

This is the controller (note the share button in the middle of the controller, which differentiates it from older models):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the current firmware version

   1. Plug the controller in via a USB cable
   2. Run this command in a terminal

      ```
      lsusb -v 2>&1 | grep -A 100 Microsoft | grep bcdDevice
      ```

      This will give you the firmware version, e.g.

      ```
      $ lsusb -v 2>&1 | grep -A 100 Microsoft | grep bcdDevice
        bcdDevice            5.01
      ```

      ⓘ The firmware is in hexadecimal, so you may see letters in the version number. For example, `5.0a` would be version 5.10, since `a` in hexadecimal is 10.

      In this example, `5.01` is firmware version 5.1 which is pretty old. According to Wikipedia, the latest firmware version is currently 5.13 (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Wireless_Controller) and look for *Current firmware* for *third revision*).
2. Update the controller firmware

   Unfortunately this can only be done in Windows via the Xbox Accessories app (available from the Microsoft Store app), or by connecting the controller to an Xbox.

   I wasn't able to update the firmware using a Windows VM running on Linux, so instead I installed Windows to an external drive and I used that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749508/14436

   In Windows, open the Xbox Accessories app and plug in your controller via a USB cable to update the firmware. More information here: https://support.xbox.com/help/hardware-network/controller/update-xbox-wireless-controller

Once the update is done, if you check the firmware version again using `lsusb` it should be a newer version, e.g.

```
$ lsusb -v 2>&1 | grep -A 100 Microsoft | grep bcdDevice
  bcdDevice            5.0d
```

(As noted above, `5.0d` is firmware version 5.13, so the controller is up to date.)

And the device should be able to connect fine over Bluetooth.

Alternatively, the device should work fine on Ubuntu if you plug it in via a USB cable, even with an older firmware.

Comment: And, how about if the controller reports 5.05 and still has the same behavior?

Comment: It definitely needs a firmware update! I realize I left an important part out of my answer: `5.0d` is the latest firmware. It corresponds to firmware version 5.13 because `d` is 13 in hexadecimal. So you're running an older version of the firmware. Hope that helps!

Comment: I can attest that I also have this  problem with firmware 5.(0x)11 so 5.17, fedora 37 with kernel 6.2.15. I could connect it once, but it hasn't been the case since....

Comment: Works fine with Ubuntu 22.04 and the Steam Deck game console.